# Add "Add Another Featured Image" Button to WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to add a button to the WordPress page editor that'll append as many featured images as the user wants? I'm basically trying to use this as a slideshow system, but I can't figure it out. There are plugins that'll allow me to set up more featured images, but nothing that will allow the user to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, if I have to create a slideshow, I use the "[Repeater](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/repeater/)" field of the [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

You could also set up a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and add your banners that way.

Comment: Thanks, the Repeater thing looks perfect.

Comment: @Rev - No worries - I think you have to purchase the repeater extension to Advanced Custom Fields, but it's cheap and really worth it!

Comment: Yea, it looks awesome, and really useful for future stuff too.